# PDFs in Zotero Web Library not synching with my local Zotfile folder

Tags: reference-managers

A new Zotero user here. I use Zotfile to put local Zotero PDFs in OneDrive. If I add a PDF file as an attachment to an entry in my desktop Zotero application, the file automatically shows up in my local OneDrive folder for Zotfile. But if I add a PDF file to an entry in the Web Library, that PDF file does not show up in the local OneDrive folder. What gives?

Thanks!

Comment: This question would best be asked on the Zotero forum at https://forums.zotero.org/ . There you will receive expert advice, not only from frequent Zotero users but also from the Zotero developers themselves. You might like specifically to check out this question and answer, ( https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/85560/zotero-online-onedrive ) noting the comment about the use of linked files.